# How to open 'RAW' file from UltraCam-Xp WA camera?

Tags: raw, file-format

Is there any software which opens Digital Camera 'RAW' file format (size- 47 mb)? I tried Photoshop cs2 but it shows stretched pixels. I tried to import it in Erdas, it also shows error that 'Unsupported raster format'. I google it and found some softwares that opens, but with those softwares I can open only RAW files less than 20 mb. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Note: This is Aerial photograph, from which I am going to do image classification. I got this 'RAW' file from client which is taken by 'UltraCam Xp-wa, S/N UC-SXp-wa-70814173' camera. They gave 'RAW' image file and corresponding 'dat' file and camera calibration report. But I don't know how to open and process it.

Comment: It would be best to contact UltraCam support. [Contact info](http://www.microsoft.com/ultracam/en-us/support.aspx) on their homepage.

Answer (score 1):

RAW data is simply the light intensity values picked up by each photosite.  Without information about the shape and color of the photosite, the RAW conversion can't properly interpret the image.  It sounds like Photoshop got fairly close, but that it uses a different shape pixel than Photoshop expected.  Your best bet is to find out if there is a RAW conversion software made by UltraCam (particularly so you can make use of the calibration file), however if that doesn't work out, you may simply want to apply an aspect ratio correction in Photoshop to account for the difference in pixel aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `RAW` files to `.DNG/.dng format` which is *Digital Negative, which is an open lossless raw image format written by Adobe used for digital photography.*

Once converted to `DNG` you can use `Photoshop/Lightroom` to edit these pictures.

While converting you can choose the *configuration* which determines the *quality* of convert.

You can find it [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=Windows&product=106)